# Linq - Get a list and sort it by a list of string values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of guids as string:

This is how i retrive my list of string guids:

```
List<string> p0 = ctx.PrProjectRating.Select(k => k).GroupBy(g => new { g.PrPIdG }, (key, group) => new { sumR = group.Sum(k => k.PrValue), pidG = key.PrPIdG }).Select(t => t.pidG).ToList();
```

Now i have another list that contains a field called pidG but this list needs to be ordered by the list of guid strings above.

How do i achiveve this.

i tried:

```
List<PProject> p = p.OrderBy(c => p0.Contains(c.PIdG)).ToList();
```

but still the list is not ordered by the string guids in the first list "p0"

Comment: Almost [the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65009459/linq-order-list-from-comparing-list-with-string-value) was asked already

Comment: i tried the answers from the related questiuons but cant find the answer

Comment: the answer from the questions is not working for me

Comment: You probably want `IndexOf()` instead of `Contains()`? Are all of the `PIdG` values guaranteed to be in `p0`?

Comment: Something like this? `var pp = p.OrderBy(c => p0.Contains(c.PIdG) ? p0.IndexOf(c.PIdG) : int.MaxValue).ToList(); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do join here

```cs
List<string> p0 = ctx.PrProjectRating
   .Select(k => k)
   .GroupBy(g => new { g.PrPIdG }, (key, group) => 
      new { sumR = group.Sum(k => k.PrValue), pidG = key.PrPIdG })
   .Select(t => t.pidG).ToList();

var result = p0.Join(p, x => x, c => c.PIdG, (x, c) => c)
   .ToList()
```